# findAndModify with remove true not removing whole document

Tags: mongodb, monk

Using [monk](https://github.com/Automattic/monk):

```
    var doc =
        yield new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            tokens.findAndModify({
                query: {
                    token: myTokenVar
                },
                remove: true,
                new: false
            }, function (err, res) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                resolve(res);
            });
        });
```

The following code above removes every field from the given document but however leaves the document with only the `_id` field left. It does not completely remove the document.

Answer (score 1):

According the [findAndModify source code](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/blob/master/lib/collection.js#L254), the `opts` object must be provided as a separate parameter. Please try it with the following codes

```
tokens.findAndModify(
            { query: {
                token: myTokenVar
            }},
            {remove: true, 'new': false}, 
            function (err, res) {
               if (err)
                  console.log(err);
               else
                  console.log(res);   
        });
```